# ClearInterval não funciona

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tenho um script que faz um Post Ajax de tempos em tempos.

#### atualizar();

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "processar.php",
        success: function(resposta){

            $("#resposta").html(resposta);
            $("#resposta").find("script").each(function(i) {
                eval($(this).text());
            });

        },complete: function(){
            setTimeout(function(){atualizar();},5000);
        }

    });
```

#### processar.php

```
if( ($result->status=='OK'){

    echo "<script>window.clearInterval(pisca['".$id_div."']);</script>";

}else{

    echo "<script>pisca['".$id_div."'] = setInterval(function(){ 
    $('#".$id_div."').animate({backgroundColor: 'white', color: 'black'}).delay(100);
    $('#".$id_div."').animate({backgroundColor: '".$fundo."', color: '".$letra."'}).delay(100);
    },100);</script>";

}
```

Passo o id da div por Post.
Porém o clearInterval não funciona.

Alguma ajuda ?

Comment: Tenta declarar a variável `pisca` no escopo global, ou seja, no início do seu script, fora de qualquer função.

Comment: Como você está usando o id da div como índice do array `pisca`, pode ser que esteja sobrescrevendo a referência à alguma chamada a `setInterval` anterior. Existe realmente necessidade do seu PHP retornar todo esse HTML? No seu caso seria mais prático retornar um JSON com os parâmetros e fazer o resto no JS mesmo.

Comment: @Oeslei Já está declarada como Global.

Comment: @AndréRibeiro Mas de qualquer forma o código não deveria funcionar desta forma ?

Comment: Deixei uma resposta que acho mais acertada do que tua solução. Se quiseres ajuda a "reparar" ou perceber porque a tua solução não funciona diz-me que tipo de valores pode `$id_div` ter? numericos ou alfa-numéricos?

Comment: Na pergunta dizes "Passo o id da div por Post.", não vejo onde estás a passar o ID...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sugiro separar as águas.

O que pertence ao lado do cliente fazer no lado do cliente, o que pertence ao lado do servidor fazer no lado do servidor. Isso implica que não se passa JavaScript do servidor para um `eval` no lado do cliente.

Sugestão:

```
var pisca = {};

function atualizar(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "processar.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: id, // este campo está em falta no teu código. Não vejo de que maneira passas a ID...
        success: function (res) {
            animar(res.id, res.status, res.data);
        },
        complete: function () {
            setTimeout(atualizar, 5000);
        }
    });
}

function animar(id, status, data) {
    if (status == 'OK') return clearInterval(pisca[id]);
    pisca.id = setInterval(function () {
        $('#' + id).animate({
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            color: 'black'
        }).delay(100);
        $('#' + id).animate({
            backgroundColor: data.fundo,
            color: data.letra
        }).delay(100);
    }, 100);
}
```

e no PHP fazer somente:

```
echo json_encode(
    'id'=>$id_div, 
    'status' => ($result->status), 
    'data' => array('fundo' => $fundo, 'letra' =>$letra)
);
```

Comment: Usei a sua idéia e funcionou perfeitamente amigo. Muitíssimo obrigado !

Comment: @PedroAugusto boa! fico contente de ter ajudado.